# Why do I get a "Conversion from string to number failed with value ''" error when connecting to Google BigQuery via the Simba ODBC driver?

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc

I'm trying to use the Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery. The connection succeeded initially, but after I enabled the High-Throughput API in "Advanced Options", I get the following error:

```
[Simba][Support] (50090) Conversion from string to number failed with value ''
```

I still get this error after unchecking the High-Throughput API option.

These are the options I initially set:

[image: advanced options dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because the [Minimum Query Results Size for HTAPI](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/htapi_minresultssize.htm) and [Ratio of Results to Rows Per Block](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/htapi_minactivationratio.htm) are both set to empty string.

Set both values to 0 to always download query results with the BigQuery Storage API.

[image]